# Angular PrimeNG Autocomplete how to pass ID value of object

Tags: angular, primeng

I seem to need some help here. Hopefully this makes sense.
I am trying to use PrimeNG autocomplete with multiple selection array.

I am filtering through object category name for the user to select but I want to pass the incidentCategoryId of the json object and I am struggling to do that.

How do I get the incidentCategoryId to be passed in the JSON form object...

Other PrimeNG options allow you to bind the value to the template

**JSON Objects**

```
[
{
    "categoryName": "Hardware",        
    "incidentCategoryId": 1
},
{
    "categoryName": "Software",      
    "incidentCategoryId": 2
},
{
    "categoryName": "Network",
    "incidentCategoryId": 3
}]
```

**.ts**

```
 filterCategory(event) {
  let filtered : any[] = [];
  let query = event.query;
  for(let i = 0; i < this.incidentcategoryService.categoryArray.length; i++) {
      let category = this.incidentcategoryService.categoryArray[i];
      if (category.categoryName.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) == 0) {
        filtered.push(category.categoryCombinedString)
    }       
  }
  this.filteredCategories = filtered;
  console.log(this.filteredCategories)
```

}

**HTML**

```
<p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="categories"[suggestions]="filteredCategories" name="incidentCategoryId" (completeMethod)="filterCategory($event)" [multiple]="true">
      </p-autoComplete>
```

**FORM VALUE JSON**

```
{
 "otherStuff": "hey I'm other stuff part of the form object being passed"
 "incidentCategory": [ "Hardware", "Software" ]
}
```

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(this.filteredCategories)` ?

Comment: {"Hardware", "Software", "Network"}

Comment: Can you instead of `category.categoryCombinedString`, just push `category` into `filtered` array?

Comment: when I do that I get [object, object] in the UI. May have to change the filter it's using

Comment: Could you please provide a stackBlitz link?